# node.js Error module.js 472 after npm install

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, react-native

after installing through npm, was also installing Expo before this error

```
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'to-fast-properties'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)  
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)  
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nbeni\Documents\Modelfy Inc Repo\Modelfy\node_modules\babel-types\lib\index.js:317:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nbeni\Documents\Modelfy Inc Repo\Modelfy\node_modules\babel-types\lib\index.js:836:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
```

Comment: looks like you don't have module `to-fast-properties`  installed

Comment: `npm i to-fast-properties`, you are missing that package.